# Need to Upgrade Gas Line Size - Cut in and add Left Right Coupling?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, gas

I have a 1 inch gas line running down my attic with several branches.  The branch going to water heater is a 1/2" branch.  I need that to be 3/4" branch per code.  However, the 1/2" branch is coming from a 1"x1/2"x3/4" tee.

Diagram of gas line layout:

[image]

Picture of gas line:

[image]

In order to change out the tee, I think I need to cut out the 29" section that's shown in my diagram and replace that section with a new pipe that's about 24" in length, a right/left coupling, and a 4" right/left nipple.  However, I'm concerned ill need to get a really really precise length for that new 1" line, because it need it to thread into the left/right coupler and the existing tee before it.  I easily remove the 1/2" line by unscrewing it as it just comes down the top plate for the wall and to the stub out.

1. Can I just get home depot to thread a new pipe section for me?  And, if it's not the size I really want, just go back and get a new one threaded?
2. I may not have a lot of play in the lines here because I'm connecting at the halfway point of an existing system.  Thoughts?
3. My thought was to turn off the gas supply, run my stove (furthest appliance from meter) until no more gas is coming out, check other appliances to make sure they aren't getting gas, then cut into the 1" line with a sawzall.  Then, after all my work is done, turn the gas on, check for leaks with the spray method and a [gas sniffer like this](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Klein-Tools-ET120-Combustible-Gas-Leak-Detector?utm_source=google_ad&utm_medium=shopping_neutral&utm_campaign=Shopping_Neutral_MPLTV&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7uSkBhDGARIsAMCZNJuDIH7VA9oK5x0HjfHsGs1XHgMTueKn6PNUE7nSXLZAa7qB2TRIbt0aAt6EEALw_wcB).

I want to hire this out but it's really hard to get a contractor to come out.  It seems like this job is too small for them and they're just not interested.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, it's illegal to work on your own gas lines.  Is there a reason you're wanting to change it other than to meet code?  My water heaters (40 gal natural gas, 3 different houses) have always has 1/2" lines, and never had a problem or concern from multiple different licensed plumbers doing connections to them.  Was code recently changed?  If so, most installations are grandfathered in, if they were code when installed even if they don't meet current code requirements.

Comment: Wow, I just looked up a 199K btu water heater.  That thing is huge unless you're wanting to install a tankless, in which case a larger gas line is certainly needed.  If that's the need, then you may need to do a use calculation to see if your supply can even provide the necessary amount of gas and if not, involve your natural gas supplier to increase pressure, and then put pressure reducers as needed at each device.

Comment: This is for a tankless water heater.  They use short bursts of natural gas.  I did a gas calculation and my meter size and overall demand is within the limits of the meter (see first pic).

Comment: It might be easier (without knowing your setup) to look at doing CSST flexible gas pipe if that's allowed for a homeowner and not licensed plumber.  You might be able to find a more accessible place to break your 1" line and add a tee at that location to feed your new water heater via CSST flex without needing to break it open at that specific location.  With the flex, that would give a lot less worry about getting pipe of exactly the correct length.  Then just cap off your existing 1/2" line and abandon in place where it comes out at your current water heater for future options.